# How to make a async/await function in AWS Lambda when using aws-sdk

Tags: javascript, promise, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am using AWS lambda to get some data from cloudwatch metric and below is my code in lambda

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');    
AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-northeast-1'});
var cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch({apiVersion: '2010-08-01'});

exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
    console.log('==== start ====');
    const connection_params = {
      // params
    };

    cloudwatch.getMetricStatistics(connection_params, function(err, data) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err, err.stack);  
        } else {
            console.log(data);      
            active_connection = data.Datapoints[0].Average.toFixed(2);
        }   
        console.log(`DDDDDDD ${active_connection}`);
    });

    console.log('AAAA');    
};
```

I always get 'AAAA' first and then get 'DDDD${active_connection }'.

But what i want is get 'DDDD${active_connection }' first and then 'AAAA'.

I tried to use like

```
cloudwatch.getMetricStatistics(connection_params).then(() => {})
```

but show

> cloudwatch.getMetricStatistics(...).then is not a function

Answer (score 2):

Try writing your code like this,

1. With `then`

```
    const x = cloudwatch.getMetricStatistics(connection_params).promise();

    x.then((response) => do something);
```

2. With `async/await`

```
    const x = await cloudwatch.getMetricStatistics(connection_params).promise();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `util#promisify` [Docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

```
const util = require("util");
const cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch();

const getMetricStatistics = util.promisify(cloudwatch.getMetricStatistics.bind(cloudwatch));

getMetricStatistics(connection_params).then(() => {})
```